# Split Smarty looped array in half

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have a simple array set in my controller for test purposes `$this->view_data['test'] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);` I want to output the array using Smarty3 to show the first half in one col and the second half in the next col.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- first half -->
    {foreach $test as $t}
        {$t}
    {/foreach}
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- second half -->
    {foreach $test as $t}
        {$t}
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and extra variable to store the array length divided by 2. Tested in smarty 3.1

```
{{assign var="cnt" value=$test|@count}} 
{{math equation="ceil(cnt/2)" cnt=$test|@count assign=dv}}
<div class="col-md-6">
{{section name=i loop=$test}}   
    {{$test[i]}}                    
{{if $smarty.section.i.iteration % $dv == 0 AND $smarty.section.i.iteration-1 < $cnt}}
</div><div class="col-md-6">
{{/if}}
{{/section}}
</div>
```